# What is the name for "pronunciation spelling"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, dictionaries, pronunciation-respelling

Dictionaries often have "pronunciation spelling" listed next to the word. For example:

> **port·man·teau** - noun `\pȯrt-ˈman-(ˌ)tō\`

What is the name for this alphabet/system? Is it a universal system, or does every language have their own "version" of it?

Comment: I realize I could easily find the answer the second question if I only I knew what the system is named, and could therefore search for it.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but in AmE, there are multiple similar [traditional respelling systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English#Traditional_respelling_systems) used by dictionaries. The guides used to be printed on the bottom of every other page.

Comment: BTW, that's not what is usually meant by "pronunciation spelling."

Comment: @Kris Thanks for pointing that out. According to the article you linked to _"Pronunciation respelling should not be confused with pronunciation spelling, which is an ad hoc spelling of a word that has no standard spelling. Most of these are [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) coinages, but some have become standardized, e.g. 'gonna' to represent the pronunciation of 'going to', as in 'I'm gonna catch you.'"_

Comment: The only word I can think of for it is *erroneous*. ;}

Comment: The very short answer to this question is "it's called IPA".

Answer (score 5):

There is a universal (more or less) system for recording human speech sounds.
It's called the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://westonruter.github.io/ipa-chart/keyboard/), or IPA.   (Note: That's *Phonetic*, **not** *Phonemic*.)
This contains all the sounds that occur in any human language.
Naturally, no human language has all of them.
No human language even has most of them.

Individual languages use only some of those sounds, and representations of words in individual languages use a special selection of these symbols -- different for every language -- called "phonemes". Usually the symbols used are taken from the IPA, but they represent only the sounds and their distribution and pronunciation **in that language**.

For instance, [this is the American English phonemic system](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), from [Kenyon and Knott](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenyon_and_Knott).

English dictionaries published in the United States normally don't use phonemic pronunciation, preferring the system invented by Noah Webster, based on spelling instead of phonetics. Webster was a spelling reformer, and believed that the traditional English spelling could be used to indicate phonetics. He was wrong, but that hasn't influenced American dictionaries.

English dictionaries published elsewhere,  or bilingual dictionaries, or dictionaries intended for language learners, normally do use standard phonemic transcription. If you have a bilingual dictionary, look at the pronunciations in the English part; they will normally use either the system of Kenyon and Knott (American) or a system of [RP (UK)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_pronunciation), which has some differences from American. This is because English speakers normally pay no attention to the pronunciations in the English part, but English learners do, and they need accuracy.

The example cited

> `\pȯrt-ˈman-(ˌ)tō\`

is the style used by Merriam-Webster, based on the original nonphonemic transcription.
In Kenyon and Knott's system, it would be

> `/portmænto/`

and in RP it would be

> `/poətmæntəʊ/`

Regardless of what the Wikipedia entry above says, the M-W system is **not** phonemic.

Comment: Why would it be any different in RP than in Kenyon and Knott’s system? Surely the phonemes in this word are the same?

Comment: Not quite. For one thing, RP has an extra low back vowel that American English lacks. Also, the British tradition (which largely predates the IPA) has been to use either long vowel marking (e.g, /e:/) or diphthongs (e.g, /eɪ/) for tense vowels (e.g, [e] as in _pay_) to contrast with lax ones (e.g, [ɛ] in _let_), where K&K use IPA vowel symbols for both: /pe/, /lɛt/. And then there's rhoticity, which is conspicuously lacking in RP, and indicated by central diphthongs: RP /foə/, USA /for/ _four, for, fore_.

Comment: I get the difference in how the tense/lax distinction is traditionally denoted—but why would ‘port’ not be /port/ in both? The extra low back vowel [ɒ] is, as far as I know, _always_ the outcome in RP of /or/, so it seems artificial to write /oə/ instead (even more so in a word like ‘pore’, where the phonemic /r/ is audible intervocalically).

Comment: Well, I agree, the phoneme is /r/ in both cases, but the set of allophones is almost completely different. ***I'd*** do it that way, but Daniel Jones got theə fə:st.

Comment: John, you have accidentally **utterly and completely ignored the actual question asked here**.  Heh!

Comment: Wait - I beg your pardon!  Like Kris, I completely misread the very confusing first sentence of the question.

Comment: @JoeBlow: No apologies necessary. The question as posed is often nonsensical and I feel no necessity to pay attention to nonsense. I only answer the questions I see as having interesting answers.

Answer (score 1):

[***Pronunciation Respelling***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English) -- "non-phonemic" or "newspaper" systems

> Pronunciation respelling is a notation used to convey the pronunciation of words, in a language, such as English, which does not have a phonemic orthography. … "non-phonemic" or "newspaper" systems, commonly used in newspapers and other non-technical writings, avoid diacritics and literally "respell" words making use of well-known English words and spelling conventions, even though the resulting system may not have a one-to-one mapping between symbols and sounds.
>
> As an example, the last name of actor Jake Gyllenhaal, written ˈdʒɪlənhɔːl in the IPA, might be written jĭl′·ən·hôl or *JIL-ən-hawl* in a phonemic system, and *Jill-in-hall* in a non-phonemic system.

Comment: Why the downvote? That was exactly what I was looking for (and in a few minutes I can accept the answer).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but -- you seem to have selected the wrong passage from that article. The OP is asking about what the article calls "'phonemic' systems", not what it calls "'non-phonemic' or 'newspaper' systems".

Comment: @ruakh What makes you think so? Can you clarify?

Comment: @IQAndreas Never mind. You can wait a day and accept the answer that suits best your purpose.

Comment: @Kris To be honest, I just skimmed your answer, and skipped immediately to the Wikipedia article you linked to. However, I see now that **@rukah** is correct. I would recommend just snipping out the second sentence from the answer, and just leaving the first and last sentences in.

Comment: @Kris Would it be too forward of me to create an edit suggestion that changes your answer a bit? (you are welcome to deny or roll back the edit if it does not satisfy)

Comment: @Kris: Sorry, it's just too explicit; I can't clarify it any further. (Maybe you missed or misread a word somewhere?) The question explicitly says that it's talking about dictionaries, and the article explicitly says that "phonemic" systems are what are found in dictionaries.

Comment: I was very pleased to learn that this is called **"newspaper system"** or "pronunciation respelling", thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for the word "transliteration". Similar to Pinyin which in Chinese means to spell out a sound....or some such....good luck.