# How to use alphabet character to pronunciation American English?

Tags: pronunciation

Because I don't know how to key in the special IPA symbols in my Chinese computer keyboard.

I'm wonder is there a simple system just use 62 (A-Za-z0-9) or less for representation the IPA symbol?  That means I don't need to key-in double dot above the u, etc.

For example the vowels(I'm trying to use a-z and dash for long vowels):

1. a - box (for o)
2. i - it
3. i- - tea (for ea)
4. oo - book
5. oo- - too
6. e - pen
7. e_ - cat (for a)
8. e- - name (for a)
9. o - dog
10. o- - no
11. u - about (for a)
12. u2 - bus (for u)
13. uu - sister (for er)
14. uu2 - bird (for ir)
15. ai - fine (for i)
16. au - how (for ow)
17. oi - boy (for oy)

for consonants

1. b - bad
2. c - chair (for ch)
3. d - desk
4. f - food
5. g - good
6. g2 - garage (for ge)
7. h - hat
8. j - joke
9. k - key
10. l - leg
11. m - mom
12. n - noon
13. n2 - sing (for ng)
14. p - pet
15. r - red
16. s - seat
17. s2 - short (for sh)
18. t - ten
19. t2 - thank (for th)
20. t3 - this (for th)
21. v - vest
22. w - we
23. y - yes
24. z - zoo

Comment: You could use [this website](http://ipa.typeit.org/full/), which has alt codes for the symbols

Comment: Related: *[Is there a standard for simplified pronunciation hints?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293307)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are any number of so-called "newspaper respelling" systems which attempt to represent pronunciation by analogy to simpler words or phonemes, avoiding the use of diacritical marks and non-Latin characters. A handful of standardized [pronunciation respelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English) systems, in alphabetic order, include the following:

- Associated Press Stylebook (subscription required)
- [ARPAbet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPABET)
- [BBC Text Spelling Guide](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/informationandarchives/BBC_Text_Spelling_guide.pdf)
- [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict?) (based on ARPAbet)
- [NBC Handbook of Pronunciation](https://archive.org/details/nbchandbookofpro00bend)
- [Voice of America Pronounce](https://pronounce.voanews.com/) (for names)
- [Wikipedia Pronunciation Respelling Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Pronunciation_respelling_key)

All of the above except the BBC system target [General American](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/united-states-of-accents-general-american/) pronunciation.

A basic flaw of all such systems is that they presuppose that the reader understands how the components of the respellings are pronounced in the reference accent. This would not be the case for a learner.

Comment: Of course, the same problem of understanding occurs, in truckloads, with IPA.

Comment: @HotLicks True, but at least in theory IPA symbols come with concrete descriptions of how to produce those speech sounds (e.g. <θ> means "a voiceless fricative with your tongue pressed against your teeth", which is infinitely more useful than "it's the sound at the end of the English word "teeth"). Sure, you won't exactly duplicate intended pronunciations of very unfamiliar sounds, but it's probably the closest you're going to get without an audio reference.

Comment: @C.Martin - Oh, and how many people even know what "fricative" means?  And if IPA is so great, how come there's no computer program that can read it and pronounce the words?

Comment: @Hot Licks: well, are you sure? https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/

Comment: @Gábor - OK!  Couldn't find before, though my Google-fu is pretty good.  (But it doesn't explain what "fricative" means.)

Comment: @Hot Licks - not, it doesn't. Still, at least IPA can be looked up rather easily and is unambiguous, something you can't really say about all those English-based but competing respellings in this answer... It's true that all those TLDR kind of people of this day and age might not know it :-) but, well, it still is the most reliable pronunciation help that exists.

Comment: @Gábor - The old Webster's scheme was easy to remember and did a good job for most words in US English.  Most people have better things to do with their time than to spend weeks learning IPA.

Comment: @Hot Licks: if all you need is to show people who don't have any exposure to any foreign language at all how to pronounce something very approximately, yes. But the world is much larger than. As to the best use of time, I'm not sure I agree but that's definitely not topical here. :-)